# Untar files outputting error

Tags: ruby, file, extract

I recently created a program that will untar a file within a specified directory. When untarring the file I get the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1423:in `stat': No such file or directory - /path/to/directory/file.file (Errno::ENOENT)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1423:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1437:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1421:in `fu_each_src_dest'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:504:in `mv'
        from spreadsheet:97:in `block in unlock_archive_spreadsheet'
        from spreadsheet:76:in `each'
        from spreadsheet:76:in `unlock_archive_spreadsheet'
        from spreadsheet:24:in `start'
        from spreadsheet:111:in `<main>'
```

When I try to run the program within the directory that it will be used in, it outputs the above error.
I'm a little confused because when I test run this program it works. For example:

```
[me@me ruby]$ ruby spreadsheet
Is this an archive spreadsheet?: y
Enter Folio # of spreadsheet if unlocking multiple use comma followed by space: 2719569
Text file containing the information is: filelist_20120625.txt
Continue: yes
Preparing to extract file..
Extracting file...
Moving file to 4000_UW_spreadsheets directory
File extracted and moved successfully
[me@me ruby]$
```

This is the source:

```
 70   require 'fileutils'
 71
 72
 73   def unlock_archive_spreadsheet
 74     print "Enter Folio # of spreadsheet if unlocking multiple use comma followed by space: "
 75     folio = gets.chomp
 76     folio.split(', ').each do |archived_file|
 77        FileUtils.chdir("path/where/file/is")
 78       
 79       archived_text_file = `grep -lr #{archived_file}.ods *.txt`
 80       tar_name = archived_text_file.match(/\d+/).to_s
 81       puts "Text file containing the information is: #{archived_text_file}"
 82       print "Continue: "
 83       continue = gets.chomp.downcase
 84       if continue.start_with?("y")
 85         puts "Preparing to extract file.."
 86        
 87         if File.exist?("/path/to/file/#{archived_file}.ods")
 88           puts "ERROR FILE EXISTS. Delete or move file and try again"
 89           raise "File: #{archived_file}.ods exists in directory. Delete or move file to continue, if file is not found within directory, contact admin."
 90           next
 91         else
 92           puts "Extracting file..."
 93           `tar -xvzf UW_archive_#{tar_name}.tgz path/to/extract/from/#{archived_file}.ods`
 94         end
 95         puts "Moving file to 4000_UW_spreadsheets directory"
 96         
 97         FileUtils.mv "/path/to/file/#{archived_file}.ods", '/path/to/move/to'
 98        
 99         puts "File extracted and moved successfully"
100       else
101         puts "Exiting.."
102         exit 1
103       end
104     end
105   end
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what is line 96 doing here? `/path/to/file/#{archived_file}.ods", 'path/to/home'`

Comment: @archana That's my mistake, it does the same as the line under it, let me take it out really quick

Comment: Please reduce your code to the bare-minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem you're seeing. "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We can't run your code to test possible fixes and trying to recreate your environment with the little you've told us isn't doable.

Comment: @theTinMan you can run the code like this..? Just use your own file paths... You wouldn't be able to run it with this members file paths anyways.. And on another note, why is this question down voted, I'm guessing the reason the paths aren't shown is because this is for a company, I wouldn't want my works file paths blasted all over stack overflow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright your problem is one of three things:

1. You don't have write permissions to the directory you're attempting to move to, I tested your code within *my own directories* and it works perfectly, good job on using FileUtils, you can use "package/gem" & "zlib" in place of the bash command, that would look something like this: 
   `extract = Gem::Package::TarReader.new(Zlib::GzipReader.open(filename_here))`
2. Your files don't exist within the archive, or there's something wrong within the archive. Check with an admin or with someone who has full perms to the directory you're going into, see if it works for them.
3. Your bash command is a little weird.. `tar -xvzf UW_archive_#{tar_name}.tgz path/to/extract/from/#{archived_file}.ods` I'm not entirely sure what you're attempting to do here. But if you need to change directories, and insist on using bash, `-C` will change into a directory. Here's a rewrite of that command: `tar -x -f UW_archive_#{tar_name}.tgz -C /path/to/change/to #{archived_file}.ods`

The `-x` tells bash to extract from a `tar` the `-f` tells it this is the filename and the `-C` says extract this filename into this directory.

That's about all I can really think of, Ruby can pretty much do everything bash can do, all you have to do is find the gem, or the library for it. Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

If extracting a single file from a large tarball within the directory inside of the tarball: `tar -x -f tarname.tgz -C path/to/extract/to path/to/file/filename.file`

That should extract the file out of the tar and into the specified directory, careful though, this will extract the file ALONG with the path, to get rid of the path you can use either, `--strip-components 1` the number is how many paths you want to strip. Or you can move the file from the paths and delete the paths themselves, hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, however I am only trying to extract a single file from a large tarball, the tarball also has a directory inside of it, not the entire tarball. Is there a way I can do that using a bash command? I already have tried using `gem/package` and it didn't work, probably due to my permissions within that folder.

Comment: @Bam I editors the answer, it should contain an answer to your question now.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for! It works!

Comment: @Bam I'd highly suggest using Ruby in place of bash, but you're welcome glad I could help, feel free to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error message, it days exactly why this operation didn't work.  You have several placeholder paths in your code still.    The placeholder is explicitly shown in the error.

Comment: `path/to/directory/file.file` is not the path to the file...

Also that doesn't explain why it works when I test run it in a different directory...?

Comment: I don't know why it works in a different directory, but you only pasted part of your program, so maybe the missing part holds a clue.  But I'm confused by your answer - are you running the code as pasted above, or are all the placeholder paths in that code something you added here on SO to obfuscate the real name of the directories you're using ?

Comment: The question lacks sufficient detail for us to be able to do much with it.

Comment: @DanFarrell I made the paths in the question because I'd rather not have everyone one stackoverflow know the directories in my companies system.. The rest of the code runs just fine and works, it has nothing to do with this specific aspect of the program.

Comment: @theTinMan What details am I missing..?

Comment: You posted an error including a path that certainly doesn't exist on your system ( /path/... ) and changed your code before sharing it, so how could we _possibly_ know why you're getting a stat error if we're not seeing the code nor the real error message?

Comment: Because the error message is the same thing, it's telling me the file doesn't exist where the file clearly exists

Comment: If you really think the `mv` operation is failing to recognize an extant file, then that would be a bug with Ruby.  But that's not the case, I'm willing to assume.  There's an error in your pathing somewhere that is causing this, but since you don't care to share your pathing with us, we can't ind it.

Comment: As a random guess, your line 77 is relative, but your error message has a leading slash, so it's absolute.  Of course, since those aren't the actual values in both your script and your error message, that could well be an error in your obfuscation.

Comment: @DanFarrell I don't understand why this is down voted? He doesn't want to show his file paths for security, you can still find the problem without the full path names..

Comment: We can't find anything because we have no idea what the directory hierarchy for his files is. We don't know where his files really are, because it's entirely possible that they're not where he thinks they are. Ruby is an extremely well tested language, especially the File and IO classes. Odds are very small the problem is in the language. And, it's a requirement that we be able to recreate the problem, or the file layout has to be perfectly defined if we're to help him. It has nothing to do with security; If he wants help he can recreate a sanitized hierarchy that hides sensitive info.

Comment: @Ekult3k, if you think you can solve the problem, then provide an answer. That's how SO works. We're trying to help, but we expect certain things. If you can read into the given question and divine the missing information then please do so. Sometimes the paths are relative, and we have NO idea where the code is running at that point, and other times it's absolute, making it independent of the current-working directory.

Comment: As another thought here, I see a lot of repeated strings.  If these were variables, not only would you not have to obfuscate the logic ( just the initial assignment ), but you'd have a good chance of solving the problem in the process.  One trick I like to use in cases like these is a string or regex based search and replace - easiest way to spot typos.

Comment: @theTinMan okay I'll post an answer.